# package javax.servlet does not exist - compilation error

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, package, tomcat9

I'm using Tomcat for university.
I have correctly set all the environment variables, taking both "servlet-api.jar" and "jsp-api.jar" and putting them in the CLASSPATH.

My teacher says that there may be two versions of java that are in conflict with each other and disturb Tomcat when it calls these packages.
Until today I have done many exercises related to servlets and JSPs and they have always worked. This problem has started to happen since I wrote JSP pages with custom tags.

When I compile the taghandler.java class it gives me these errors. If I compile it with `javac -cp path to jsp-api.jar and servlet-api.jar filename.java` compile it correctly, while if I do the classic compilation `javac filename.java` of class taghandler does not work.

Moreover when I have to compile with two different libraries or the javax.servlet and javax.servlet.jsp I have problems because with `` `javac - cp path ...` `` I can pass only one path for each library.

Can you tell me how can I solve the problem ??

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: The -cp flag can take more then one Jar file. Simply separate them with ; character.

Comment: @Michal in this way...?
`javac -cp path/servlet-api.jar namefile.java;path/jsp-api.jar namefile.java`

Comment: Like this:  `javac -cp path/servlet-api.jar;path/jsp-api.jar namefile.java`